# how to get multiple xml-elements without using xmlaggregation

Tags: xml, oracle

I need to create the following xml-structure from an oracle-database
where each survey can multiple participants.
I'm not sure to create this using XMLElement without getting the message "ORA-01427 subsquery returns more then one row"
I could try to use dbms_xmldom (never done that before) but I'm wondering if anyone knows how to generate this just using the plain Oracle SQL-XMLfunctions (XMLElement, XMLAggr)

```
    <NieuweSurveys>
        <Survey>
            <Surveynaam>2013-02-01</Surveynaam>         
            <Startdatum>2013-02-01</Startdatum>
            <Einddatum>2013-02-15</Einddatum>
            <Deelnemer>
                <Voornaam>Tilde</Voornaam>
                <Tussenvoegsel/>
                <Achternaam>DeelnemerA</Achternaam>
                <Geslacht>man</Geslacht>
                <Emailadres>tilde.deelnemer.a@tjip.com</Emailadres>
                <Voorkeurstaal>nl</Voorkeurstaal>
                <Account>Schouten & Nelisen</Account>
                <Functie>bouwer</Functie>
            </Deelnemer>
            <Deelnemer>
                <Voornaam>Tilde</Voornaam>
                <Tussenvoegsel/>
                <Achternaam>DeelnemerB</Achternaam>
                <Geslacht>vrouw</Geslacht>
                <Emailadres>tilde.deelnemer.b@tjip.com</Emailadres>
                <Voorkeurstaal>nl</Voorkeurstaal>
                <Account>Schouten & Nelisen</Account>
                <Functie>tester</Functie>
            </Deelnemer>
        </Survey>
</NieuweSurveys>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the data comes from a single table (or view) called dataview ...

I think you are going to need to use XMLForest in there. For example,

```
Create or Replace VIEW dataviewxml as
Select 
XMLElement("NieuweSurveys", 
 XMLForest(d.Surveynaam as Surveynaam, d.Startdatum as Startdatum, d.Eindatum as Eindatum,
  XMLForest(d.Voornaam as Voornaam, d.Tussenvoegsel as Tussenvoegsel
           ) as "Deelnemer"
         ) as "Survey"
         ) as "Result"
from dataview d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XQuery expression with SQL/XML standard function `XMLQuery` or `XMLTable`.
Here are two examples that should be relevant for constructing XML from relational data:

- using `XMLQuery`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#CBAJHHJD
- using `XMLTable`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#CBAJEGFH